# <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> Eclipse photon jdk 10 Tomcat 9

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9, eclipse-photon

I'm working on a project for my university. In that project, we should create a web service with eclipse photon, Tomcat 9 and Java 10.

I've already installed the eclipse, tomcat, axis2, and java.

eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

java: 10-JDK

axis2: axis2-1.7.8

Also, my eclipse is fully configured (standard configuration with necessary settings for tomcat, java, and axis) and the tomcat server is running.
My problem is when I create a web service I'll get the following error message for one line in different files created during web service construction.

Cannot find the tag library descriptor for <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

I've tried with different versions for eclipse and tomcat. Think there is an error in versions. All FAQ and articles I've found are made with previous versions and they solve this. So I'm convinced that somebody can give assistance

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks so much and If you need further information I'll try to collect and share.

Answer (score 2):

You need the dependency my friend. Dependency is missing for that particular descriptor. 
If you are working using maven project and want add dependency or you wanna download (for both) I'm sharing a link with you. 
--> Download or copy paste the dependency to the POM.XML file.

--> If you download then project-->build path --> Configure Build Path --> Libraries --> Add External Jars. Put your jar file here.

LINK : `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this error comes when you do not have `jstl` jar file.

Please, add these two files and this error should go away:

1. `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-version`
2. `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-version`

This is working 100% for me in Eclipse.

Note: right now I am not using Maven but these can be added in `pom.xml` as well.